# Combinatorics - Number of ways to distribute Candies Among Children; each child having a limit of maximum candies they can receive

Tags: combinatorics

There are a lot of variants on math.stackexchange but I haven't seen this problem (yet).
I'm trying to calculate the number of ways to distribute $n$ candies among $3$ children such that no children gets more than $l$ candies.
$n$ is smaller or equal to $3l$ otherwise there would not be any possibility to solve the problem.

My reasoning is the following. Let $k$ be the number of candies I give to the first child.
$k$ is at least $\max(0, n-2*l)$ and at most $\min(l, n)$ ensuring the range of $k$ is correctly bounded considering both the total candies and the limit per child.

With $k$ fixed, the number of ways to give the $n-k$ remaining candies is $\max(0, 2*\min(n-k, l)-(n-k)+1)$. This is because the second child must at least receive $n-k-\min(n-k, l)$ candies (meaning the other would get $\min(n-k, l)$ candies) and at most $\min(n-k, l)$ candies.

My final formula is therefore:
$\sum_{k=\max(0, n-2l)}^{\min(l, n)} \max(0, 2*\min(n-k, l)-(n-k)+1)$

I cannot find a way to simply this sum, but I feel like I could get an easier analytical result.

Comment: One could use stars-and-bars to find the number of ways to distribute candies without the restriction. Then one would have to subtract the combinations where a child got more than $l$ candies using the inclusion-exclusion. I doubt this would yield a nice closed formula though.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, I'm going to look into it. As long as I have a formula without a sum I would feel happy as computing it would go from a linear complexity to a constant time.

Comment: There still will be a sum.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows The Stars and bars + PIE approach should yield a sum with ~4 terms in it, unlike yours with $n$ terms in it. If that's not what you get, can you write out what you're thinking it is?

Comment: @Aig, I don't think so, cf. my answer.

Comment: @CalvinLin I tried to formalise it as much as I could. Would you mind taking a look to make sure I didn't make a mistake? :)

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows indeed a nice formula. I’m glad my idea was able to help you, although I didn’t quite believe it myself

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found out a way to solve the problem using The Stars and bars + PIE approach.

The first thing is to consider what is number of situations where candies are all distributed to the three children and allowing children to get more than limit. This is $n + 2$ chooses $2$ (Stars and bars)

Then, we need to subtract the situations where at least one of the children gets more than $l$. We first "give" a child $l+1$ candies (thus ensuring that child is over the limit), and then distribute the remaining $n−(l+1)$ = $n - l - 1$ candies among all 3 children. This is $(n - l - 1 + 2)$ chooses $2$ (Stars and bars). This needs to be multiplied by 3 since we "chose" a child with too many candies but any of the three children could have too many candies.

However, there are situations where two children get more than limit, and we subtracted these situations twice, so we need to add them back. To do so, we first "give" the first child $l+1$ candies, and the second child $l+1$ candies, and then distribute the remaining $n−2∗(l+1) = n - 2l - 2$ candies among all $3$ children. This is $n - 2l - 2 + 2$ chooses $2$ (Stars and bars). This needs to be multiplied by $3$ chooses $2$ because this could happen to any of two children out of three.

Formula is therefore:

$\text{Total Ways} = \binom{n+2}{2} - 3 \times \binom{n-l-1+2}{2} + \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{n-2l-2+2}{2}$

Of course everything I've described assumes with n = 9, solutions (1, 4, 4), (4, 1, 4) and (4, 4, 1) are distinct.

Also if $n$ is not bigger than $l + 1$ the second term does not need to be considered since no child can have more than $l$ candies. And if $n$ is not bigger than $2*(l+1)$, the third term does not need to be considered since it is not possible for two children to have both more than $l$ candies.

Comment: Looks good. And in a similar manner, you can deal with the scenario where child $i$ doesn't get more than $l_i$ candies. There could be up to $2^n$ terms to allow for that flexibility.